# How is writing the MSBuild for a Silverlight project different?

Tags: silverlight, msbuild

I have the Import:

```
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.tar ets" />
```

and a bunch of Silverlight specific PropertyGroups such as:

```
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
  <NoStdCfg>true</NoStdCfg>
  -----etc.
```

How do I write targets that use the above?

**EDIT**

I also have these references:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="mscorlib" />
<Reference Include="system" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass all properties to MSBuild task:

```
<Target Name="....">
   <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectsToBuild)" 
            Properties="TargetFrameworkVersion=$(TargetFrameworkVersion); ... "/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did that but am getting errors. Is there a list of required properties for a Silverlight solution (with multiple projects)?

Comment: @Shazam : http://www.dieajax.com/2007/10/03/10-minute-tutorial-silverlight-building-a-silverlight-application-with-msbuild-c/

Comment: @Shazam: http://khason.net/blog/msbuild-tasks-for-build-machines-for-wpf-and-silverlight/